# Submitting changes to a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

i have the following web API Controller and working great, and able to update record using the API but i want to create UI controller to post the changes to the database using asp view pages, i can  post changes from the API but i need to update using Views

API Controller:

```
[HttpPut("Products/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProduct(int id, ProductDTO updatedProduct)
{
    updatedProduct = await ProductService.UpdateProductAsync(id, updatedProduct);
    return Ok(updatedProduct);
}
```

UI controller to edit/update product:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null) 
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var ProductList = (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();
    var Product = ProductList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);
    if (Product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(Product);
}

[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProduct([FromRoute]int id, [FromBody]ProductDTO updatedProduct)
{
    updatedProduct = await ProductService.UpdateProductAsync(id, updatedProduct);
    return Ok(updatedProduct);
}
```

IProductService:

```
public interface IProductService
{
    Task<ProductDTO> UpdateProductAsync(int id, ProductDTO updatedProduct);
}
```

Edit View:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Product" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" value="@Model.Id" class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" asp-for="Code" value="@Model.Code" class="form-control" />
    <button class="btn btn-success Product-edit-button" role="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

how can post changes to database

Comment: Where is your context in your datalayer?

Comment: @StuiterSlurf  i have a PDMcontext in the data layer all great, i have product as `public virtual DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }`

Comment: Well in that data layer you need to call the savechangesasync method of the context to save the changes to the database?

Comment: `public interface IProductService
{
    Task<ProductDTO> UpdateProductAsync(int id, ProductDTO updatedProduct);
}` i have this in my question

Answer (score 0):

You could not use `FromBody` to receive the data from form submit, it gets values from the request body instead of  from posted form fields.

Remove the `[HttpPut("{id}")]` and use below action to receive your updated form:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, ProductDTO updatedProduct)
```

Comment: I get this eror `http://localhost:43216/api/Product/Products/{id} with status code InternalServerError. Error Content: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'ProductKey')`